# NumPy or Pandas: Keeping array type as integer while having a NaN value

Tags: python, numpy, int, pandas, type-conversion

Is there a preferred way to keep the data type of a `numpy` array fixed as `int` (or `int64` or whatever), while still having an element inside listed as `numpy.NaN`?

In particular, I am converting an in-house data structure to a Pandas DataFrame. In our structure, we have integer-type columns that still have NaN's (but the dtype of the column is int). It seems to recast everything as a float if we make this a DataFrame, but we'd really like to be `int`.

Thoughts?

**Things tried:**

I tried using the `from_records()` function under pandas.DataFrame, with `coerce_float=False` and this did not help. I also tried using NumPy masked arrays, with NaN fill_value, which also did not work. All of these caused the column data type to become a float.

Comment: Could you use a numpy masked array?

Comment: I'll give it a try. I also tried the `from_records` function under pandas.DataFrame, with `coerce_float=False`, but no luck... it still makes the new data have type `float64`.

Comment: Yeah, no luck. Even with masked array, it still converts to float. It's looking like Pandas goes like this: "Is there a NaN anywhere? ... Then everything's a float." Hopefully there is a way around this.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

[This capability has been added to pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html) beginning with [version 0.24](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support).

At this point, it requires the use of extension dtype `'Int64'` (capitalized), rather than the default dtype `'int64'` (lowercase).

Comment: For now you have to specify a special dtype like `'Int64'` to make it work. It will be even better when it will be enabled by default.

Comment: This is great! There's a small issue though that PyCharm fails to display the dataframe in the debug window if used this way. You can see my answer for another question for how to force displaying it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38956660/dataframe-not-showing-in-pycharm/53288781#53288781 (the original problem there is different, but the solution for displaying the dataframe works)

Comment: Do I have to use `'Int64'` or is there something like `'Int8'`? It uses an insane amount of memory compared to `np.float`.

Comment: `'Int8'` seems to work, but `np.float` still seems to load way faster. Issue seems to be that it isn't releasing memory inbetween. Assume garbage collector will eventually run.

Answer (score 128):

`NaN` can't be stored in an integer array. This is a known limitation of pandas at the moment; I have been waiting for progress to be made with NA values in NumPy (similar to NAs in R), but it will be at least 6 months to a year before NumPy gets these features, it seems:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na

(This feature has been added beginning with version 0.24 of pandas, but note it requires the use of extension dtype Int64 (capitalized), rather than the default dtype int64 (lower case):
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support
)

Comment: Hi Wes, is there any update on this? We run into issues that join columns are converted into either ints or floats, based on the existence of a NA value in the original list. (Creating issues later on when trying to merge these dataframes)

Comment: Updated link:  http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support

Answer (score 12):

In case you are trying to convert a float (1.143) vector to integer (1), and that vector has NAs, converting it to the new 'Int64' dtype will give you an error. In order to solve this you have to round the numbers and then do ".astype('Int64')"

```
s1 = pd.Series([1.434, 2.343, np.nan])
#without round() the next line returns an error 
s1.astype('Int64')
#cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64
##with round() it works
s1.round().astype('Int64')
0      1
1      2
2    NaN
dtype: Int64
```

My use case is that I have a float series that I want to round to int, but when you do .round() still has decimals, you need to convert to int to remove decimals.

Comment: For future seekers, i was receiving errors with this approach. Then i noticed there was a difference on the case for the integer. Note that `Int64` != `int64`. Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 9):

If performance is not the main issue, you can store strings instead.

```
df.col = df.col.dropna().apply(lambda x: str(int(x)) )
```

Then you can mix then with `NaN` as much as you want. If you really want to have integers, depending on your application, you can use `-1`, or `0`, or `1234567890`, or some other dedicated value to represent `NaN`.

You can also temporarily duplicate the columns: one as you have, with floats; the other one experimental, with ints or strings. Then inserts `asserts` in every reasonable place checking that the two are in sync. After enough testing you can let go of the floats.

Answer (score 8):

This is not a solution for all cases, but mine (genomic coordinates) I've resorted to using 0 as NaN

```
a3['MapInfo'] = a3['MapInfo'].fillna(0).astype(int)
```

This at least allows for the proper 'native' column type to be used, operations like subtraction, comparison etc work as expected

Answer (score 7):

#### Pandas v0.24+

Functionality to support `NaN` in integer series will be available in v0.24 upwards. There's [information on this](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support) in the v0.24 "What's New" section, and more details under [Nullable Integer Data Type](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/user_guide/integer_na.html#integer-na).

#### Pandas v0.23 and earlier

In general, it's best to work with `float` series where possible, even when the series is upcast from `int` to `float` due to inclusion of `NaN` values. This enables vectorised NumPy-based calculations where, otherwise, Python-level loops would be processed.

The docs do [suggest](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na) : "One possibility is to use `dtype=object` arrays instead." For example:

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, np.nan])

print(s.astype(object))

0      1
1      2
2      3
3    NaN
dtype: object
```

For cosmetic reasons, e.g. output to a file, this *may* be preferable.

#### Pandas v0.23 and earlier: background

[`NaN` is considered a `float`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558973/why-is-nan-considered-as-a-float). The [docs currently (as of v0.23)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na) specify the reason why integer series are upcasted to `float`:

> In the absence of high performance NA support being built into NumPy
>   from the ground up, the primary casualty is the ability to represent
>   NAs in integer arrays.
>
> This trade-off is made largely for memory and performance reasons, and
>   also so that the resulting Series continues to be “numeric”.

The docs also [provide rules](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/gotchas.html#na-type-promotions) for upcasting due to `NaN` inclusion:

```
Typeclass   Promotion dtype for storing NAs
floating    no change
object      no change
integer     cast to float64
boolean     cast to object
```

Answer (score 3):

### New for Pandas v1.00 +

You do not (and can not) use `numpy.nan` any more.
Now you have `pandas.NA`.

Please read: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html

> IntegerArray is currently experimental. Its API or implementation may
> change without warning.
>
> Changed in version 1.0.0: Now uses pandas.NA as the missing value
> rather than numpy.nan.
>
> In Working with missing data, we saw that pandas primarily uses NaN to
> represent missing data. Because NaN is a float, this forces an array
> of integers with any missing values to become floating point. In some
> cases, this may not matter much. But if your integer column is, say,
> an identifier, casting to float can be problematic. Some integers
> cannot even be represented as floating point numbers.

Answer (score 2):

If there are blanks in the text data, columns that would normally be integers will be cast to floats as float64 dtype because int64 dtype cannot handle nulls. This can cause inconsistent schema if you are loading multiple files some with blanks (which will end up as float64 and others without which will end up as int64

This code will attempt to convert any number type columns to Int64 (as opposed to int64) since Int64 can handle nulls

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#show datatypes before transformation
mydf.dtypes

for c in mydf.select_dtypes(np.number).columns:
    try:
        mydf[c] = mydf[c].astype('Int64')
        print('casted {} as Int64'.format(c))
    except:
        print('could not cast {} to Int64'.format(c))

#show datatypes after transformation
mydf.dtypes
```

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible, since pandas v 0.24.0

[pandas 0.24.x release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support)
Quote: "**Pandas has gained the ability to hold integer dtypes with missing values.**

Comment: What does this add that [techvslife's answer](/a/51997100/4518341) doesn't? Please don't post duplicate answers.

Answer (score 0):

I know that OP has asked for NumPy or Pandas only, but I think it is worth mentioning [polars](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars) as an alternative that supports the requested feature.

> In `Polars` any missing values in an integer column are simply `null` values and the column remains an integer column.

See [Polars - User Guide > Coming from Pandas](https://docs.pola.rs/user-guide/migration/pandas/#missing-data) for more info.