# Efficient method for getting elementwise types in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, performance, types, pandas

Following up on [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value), is there a preferred efficient manner to get the type of each object within a column? This is specifically for the case where the `dtype` of the column is `object` to allow for heterogeneous types among the elements of the column (in particular, allowing for numeric `NaN` without changing the data type of the other elements to `float`).

I haven't done time benchmarking, but I am skeptical of the following immediately obvious way that comes to mind (and variants that might use `map` or `filter`). The use cases of interest need to quickly get info on the types of all elements, so generators and the like probably won't be an efficiency boon here.

```
# df is a pandas DataFrame with some column 'A', such that
# df['A'].dtype is 'object'

dfrm['A'].apply(type) #Or np.dtype, but this will fail for native types.
```

Another thought was to use the NumPy `vectorize` function, but is this really going to be more efficient? For example, with the same setup as above, I could try:

```
import numpy as np
vtype = np.vectorize(lambda x: type(x)) # Gives error without lambda

vtype(dfrm['A'])
```

Both ideas lead to workable output, but it's the efficiency I'm worried about.

**Added**

I went ahead and did a tiny benchmark in IPython. First is for `vtype` above, then for the `apply` route. I repeated it a dozen or so times, and this example run is pretty typical on my machine.

The `apply()` approach clearly wins, so is there a good reason to expect that I won't get more efficient than with `apply()`?

**For `vtype()`**

```
In [49]: for ii in [100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000]:
   ....:     dfrm = pandas.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(ii)})
   ....:     dfrm['A'] = dfrm['A'].astype(object)
   ....:     dfrm['A'][0:-1:2] = None
   ....:     st_time = time.time()
   ....:     tmp = vtype(dfrm['A'])
   ....:     ed_time = time.time()
   ....:     print "%s:\t\t %s"%(ii, ed_time-st_time)
   ....:     
100:         0.0351531505585
1000:        0.000324010848999
10000:       0.00209212303162
100000:      0.0224051475525
1000000:     0.211136102676
10000000:    2.2215731144
```

**For `apply()`**

```
In [50]: for ii in [100,1000,10000,100000,1000000,10000000]:
   ....:     dfrm = pandas.DataFrame({'A':np.random.rand(ii)})
   ....:     dfrm['A'] = dfrm['A'].astype(object)
   ....:     dfrm['A'][0:-1:2] = None
   ....:     st_time = time.time()
   ....:     tmp = dfrm['A'].apply(type)
   ....:     ed_time = time.time()
   ....:     print "%s:\t %s"%(ii, ed_time-st_time)
   ....:     
100:         0.000900983810425
1000:        0.000159025192261
10000:       0.00117015838623
100000:      0.0111050605774
1000000:     0.103563070297
10000000:    1.03093600273
```

Comment: Minor note: `lambda x: type(x)` will be slower than simply `type`, I think.

Comment: Yeah, that's true. No need for the lambdas. Edited.

Comment: Although, for my `vtype` function, I am getting an error when I don't define it with the lambda.

Comment: Yeah, vectorize is a little more finicky about what it accepts.  If the other objects are numerical you could use `.apply(isnan)`, I guess, but that won't work if they're strings.

Comment: Yeah, it will need to be more than just nan checking. Also, pandas provides the `.isnull()` function which I generally find to be better than NumPy `isnan()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Series.apply` and `Series.map` use a specialized Cython method (`pandas.lib.map_infer`) I wrote that is roughly 2x faster than using `numpy.vectorize`.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback. We are also noticing that for small benchmark tests (up to length 10,000,000 columns), it seems that the code `dfrm['A'].apply(type).unique()` performs basically just the same as `set([type(x) for x in dfrm['A'] if x is not None])` ... is this because of some NumPy overhead to return a NumPy array at the end?

Comment: I think in both cases you're going to be limited by hash table performance. But I could be wrong; there is additional overhead to converting the internal result of unique to an ndarray, so I'm sure is contributing.