# Converting data to missing in pandas

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a `DataFrame` with a mix of 0's and other numbers.  I would like to convert the 0's to missing.

For example, I am looking for the command that would convert

```
In [618]: a=DataFrame(data=[[1,2],[0,1],[1,2],[0,0]])

In [619]: a
Out[619]: 
   0  1
0  1  2
1  0  1
2  1  2
3  0  0
```

to

```
In [619]: a
Out[619]: 
   0   1
0  1   2
1  NaN 1
2  1   2
3  NaN NaN
```

I tried pandas.replace(0, NaN), but I get an error that NaN is not defined.  And I don't see anywhere to import NaN from.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just do `from numpy import nan`.  (You will have to convert your DataTable to float type, because you can't use `NaN` in integer arrays.)

Comment: it doesn't work, because the type of the columns is int:  `ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer`

Comment: Well, then you'll have to convert the data to floats.  You can't use `NaN` with integer data structures.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value .

Comment: so you should explain this in your answer, in the moment the answer doesn't fit to the question.