# How do you represent missing data in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, na

Does Pandas have an equivalent of R's **na** (meaning not available)? If not, what is the convention for representing a missing value, as opposed to NaN which represents a mathematically impossible value such as a divide by zero?

Comment: To clarify, I was looking for a representation for NA that is distinct from NaN, which seems not to exist in pandas/numpy.

Comment: As for 2022, you can use `pandas.NA` to represent a missing value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently there is no NA value available in Pandas or NumPy. From the section "Working with missing data" in the Pandas manual (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html):

> The choice of using NaN internally to denote missing data was largely for simplicity and performance reasons. It differs from the MaskedArray approach of, for example, `scikits.timeseries`. We are hopeful that NumPy will soon be able to provide a native NA type solution (similar to R) performant enough to be used in pandas.

Also, this part of the documentation (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions) provides more details on the trade-offs in this choice of NA representation.

Comment: See also [NumPy or Pandas: Keeping array type as integer while having a NaN value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value/11548224#11548224)

Comment: As for 2022, you can use pandas.NA to represent a missing value. –

Answer (score 1):

It comes from [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/misc.html)

```
from numpy import nan
x = nan
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it from `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np
np.nan
```

or simply

```
float('NaN')
```

In pandas docs the `np.nan` version is used mostly: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/missing_data.html