# How to convert a column data type from 'string ' to 'boolean', preserving NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, nan, python-3.7

I have a column in dataframe of data type object which basically composed of a lot of missing values as NaN and some strings as 'False' and 'True' entries. I want to convert it to boolean data type but the NaN entries get converted to True. How to Do this with preserving the NaN values as it is?

1- I've tried the .astype() method which returned the NaN values as True.
2- Tried to convert first to numeric then to boolean and ended up with the same result.

```py
# Before conversion

In[]:  ri_df.contraband_weapons.value_counts()
Out[]: False    11296
       True       499
       Name: contraband_weapons, dtype: int64

# After conversion

In[]:  ri_df.contraband_weapons.astype('bool').value_counts()
Out[]: True     498385
       False     11296
       Name: contraband_weapons, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting boolean pandas column that supports NA/ is nullable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34520267/getting-boolean-pandas-column-that-supports-na-is-nullable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a comment by *Stef* I changed completely my answer:

If you have your colum as **string** *'True'* or  *'False'* intermixed with
*NaN* values, you can use *replace* with a dictionary:

- replace string *'True'* with **boolean** *True*,
- replace string *'False'* with **boolean** *False*.

Something like:

```
ri_df.contraband_weapon.replace({'True': True, 'False': False}, inplace=True)
```

So the code can be quite short.

But the bad news is that the type of this column is still **object**.
The reason is that:

- most values are of *bool* type,
- but some of them are *NaN*, which is actually a special case of *float*.

Hence, there is no any "single" type among values in this column,
so the type can not be *bool*.

## Edit following the question about "workaround"

I see that you want to preserve the "three value logic" (*True* / *False* / *Unknown*).

If you want to stay with native *Pandas* data types, I think there is no workaround, because:

- *bool* is either *True* or *False* (not third option as "unknown"),
- *NaN* is a special case of *float*,

so you have to live with this "mixture of types".

Maybe some alternative is to define a *Categorical* type, including three
categories, corresponding to *True*, *False* and *Unknown* and tranlate
each source value to a respective category.

Then there will be a **single** data type, but the dowside is that if you
want to have any "3-value bool operators / functions", you have to program
them on your own.

Comment: The question reads "How to convert a column data type from 'string ' to 'boolean'?", so I think the original datatype is string and not bool.

Comment: @Valdi_Bo Thank you for your valuable contribution. The first part of your answer using a dict to map the values works fine but isn't there any workaround to get the column dtype converted to boolean with preserving the NaN values as Missing entries neither True nor False.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval` to convert string `'True'`/`'False'` to boolean `True`/`False` and leave the NaNs untouched:

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'Col1': ['True', np.nan, 'False']})
df.applymap(type)
#              Col1
#0    <class 'str'>
#1  <class 'float'>
#2    <class 'str'>
df.loc[~df.Col1.isnull(),'Col1'] = df[~df.Col1.isnull()].Col1.map(eval)
df.applymap(type)
#              Col1
#0   <class 'bool'>
#1  <class 'float'>
#2   <class 'bool'>
```

Comment: can you try with `df[~df.Col1.isnull()].Col1.map(ast.literal_eval)` , which should be a better option than `eval`

Comment: @anky_91 `ast.literal_eval` works too - why is it a better option than `eval`?

Comment: umm i just dont prefer it :) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) is the reason , but `ast` module is specifically made for this so that should be safer check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)

Comment: @anky_91 `literal_eval` isn't mentioned in the link, it just explains that in many cases you could do without eval (as in our case, where we could use e.g. np.where), but I just read the docs of literal_eval stating "This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself.", so it might be better indeed. Thanks for the comment, I didn't know the `ast` module before.

Comment: did you check the second link too? bdw np :)

Comment: @anky_91 oops, my bad, I overlooked it. Thanks.