# Dataframe not showing in Pycharm

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I am using PyCharm 2016.2.1 . When I try to view a Pandas dataframe through the newly added feature 'View as DataFrame' in the debugger, this works as expected for a small (e.g. 4x4) DataFrame.

However when I try to view a DataFrame (generated by custom script) of ~10,000 rows x ~50 columns, I get the message: "Nothing to show".

When I run the same script (that generates the DataFrame) in Spyder, I am able to view it, so I am pretty sure it's not an error in my script.

Does anyone know if there is a maximum size to the DataFrames that can be viewed in PyCharm, and if there is a way to change this?

## EDIT:

It seems that the maximum size allowed is 1000 x 15 , as in some cases it gets truncated to this size (when the number of rows is too large, but when there are too many columns pycharm just says 'nothing to show').

Still, I would like to know if there is a way to increase the maximum allowed rows and columns viewable through the DataFrame viewer.

Comment: It doesn't work yet with multiindex dataframes either, big or small. I think either this is a bug, or the feature is incomplete.

Comment: by the way, sometimes you are able to see a part of the dataframe by editing the line in the viewer to look something like df.iloc[0:100,0:10]

Comment: I'm using v2018.3 and still facing the same issue :/

Comment: version 2019.1 - still the same problem...

Comment: greetings from 2019 lol

Comment: April 2020 still not working properly, as it seems

Comment: greetings from May 2020

Answer (score 24):

I have faced the same problem with `PyCharm 2018.2.2`. The reason was having a special character in a column's name as mentioned by Yunzhao .

If your having a column name like 'R&D' changing it to 'RnD' will fix the problem. It's really strange JetBrains hasn't solved this problem for over 2 years.

Comment: I don't think it's even just special characters. I couldn't view a dataframe in SciView until I returned a column named "TERMINATION_OF_EFFECTIVE_COV". I found it in my DataFrame by dropping each column one-by-one until the DataFrame loaded in SciView. Hope this helps someone else

Answer (score 12):

As you said in your edit, there's a limit on the number of columns (on my PC though it's far less than 15). However, you can see the whole thing by typing:

```
df.values
```

It will show you the whole dataframe, but without the names of the columns.

---

**Edit:**

To show the column names as well:

```
np.vstack([df.columns, df.values])
```

Answer (score 9):

I have met the same problems. 
I figured it was because of the special characters in column names (in my case)
In my case, I have "%" in the column name, then it doesn't show the data in View as DataFrame function. After I remove it, everything was correctly shown.
Please double check if you also have some special characters in the column names.

Answer (score 9):

This might be helpful for some people experiencing similar problem:

As of August 2019 `SciView` in PyCharm does struggle with displaying `DataFrame`s that have contain **nullable integer type**, see [issue on JetBrains](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-34650)

Answer (score 5):

I use PyCharm 2019.1.1 (Community Edition). And when I used right-click "View as DataFrame". I get the message: "Nothing to show".

But when I click the object tail button "...View as DataFrame", it worked.
 [image]

I find out that my problem is my DataFrame Object is an Object's param. Right-click the "View as DataFrame" doesn't transfer the class name, need to user input the class's name and param's name.

Hope can help somebody.

Answer (score 4):

In the case that you don't strictly need to use the functionalities given by the DataFrame viewer, you can print the whole DataFrame in the output window, using:

```
def print_full(x):
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', len(x))
    print(x)
    pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')
```

Answer (score 2):

I use PyCharm 2019.1.1 (Community Edition) and I run Python 3.7.
When I first click on "View as DataFrame" there seems to be the same issue, but if I wait a few second the content pops up. For me it is a matter of loading.

Answer (score 2):

In my situation, the problem is caused by two same cloumn name in my dataframe.
Check it by:`len(list(df)) == len(set(df))`

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of completeness: I face the same problem, due to the fact that some elements in the index of the dataframe contain a question mark '?'. One should avoid that too, if you still want to use the data viewer. Data viewer still worked, if the index strings contain hashes or less-than/greather-than signs though.

Answer (score 1):

As of 2020-10-02, using PyCharm 2020.1.4, I found that this issue also occurs if the DataFrame contains a column containing a tuple.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing is happening to me in version 2021.3.3

In my case, it seems to have something to do with the column dtype being `Int64`, but then completely full of `<NA>` values. As soon as I change even a single row's value in the offending column to an actual integer, it renders again.

So, if feasible, you can fix it by dropping the column, or setting all (or at least one) of the values to some meaningful replacement value, like `-1` or `-99999` or something:

```
df["col"] = df["col"].fillna(value=-1)
```