# How to deal with data with pandas without influencing nan?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a string series with some nan, and I want to replace some characters and then turn it into int(float is ok) but nan still remain nan. Like

```
In[1]:df = pd.DataFrame(["type 12", None, "type13"], columns=['A'])
Out[1]: 
  A
0 12
1 NaN
2 13
```

Is there any good way to do it?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet?

Comment: Please check [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and add desired output too. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NumPy or Pandas: Keeping array type as integer while having a NaN value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value)

Comment: Already update question

Answer (score 1):

No, unfortunately. You will have to settle for `floats`.

```
>>> s = pd.Series(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'], index=list('abcde'))
>>> s
a    1
b    2
c    3
d    4
e    5
dtype: object
>>> s = s.reindex(['a','b','c','f','u'])
>>> s
a      1
b      2
c      3
f    NaN
u    NaN
dtype: object
>>> s.astype(int)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/juan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2947, in astype
    raise_on_error=raise_on_error, **kwargs)
  File "/home/juan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2873, in astype
    return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
  File "/home/juan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 2832, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
  File "/home/juan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 422, in astype
    values=values, **kwargs)
  File "/home/juan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/internals.py", line 465, in _astype
    values = com._astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
  File "/home/juan/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 2628, in _astype_nansafe
    return lib.astype_intsafe(arr.ravel(), dtype).reshape(arr.shape)
  File "pandas/lib.pyx", line 937, in pandas.lib.astype_intsafe (pandas/lib.c:16620)
  File "pandas/src/util.pxd", line 60, in util.set_value_at (pandas/lib.c:67979)
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

From Pandas [Caveats and Gotchas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#nan-integer-na-values-and-na-type-promotions):

> The special value NaN (Not-A-Number) is used everywhere as the NA
>   value, and there are API functions isnull and notnull which can be
>   used across the dtypes to detect NA values.
>
> However, it comes with it a couple of trade-offs which I most
>   certainly have not ignored... In the absence of high performance NA
>   support being built into NumPy from the ground up, **the primary
>   casualty is the ability to represent NAs in integer arrays.**

So work with this:

```
>>> s.astype(float)
a    1.0
b    2.0
c    3.0
f    NaN
u    NaN
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I need to do some preprocess. Is there any good way to do it?

Comment: @modkzs so are you saying your column values literally contain "type 12" as strings and you want to extract the "12" for instance?