# Take first 6 digits of Pandas Column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a task to take the first 6 digits of a column in pandas. However, if this number is less than 6 digits long it adds a decimal to the end of the number. Unfortunately, this is not acceptable for my needs later down the road.

I'm sure I can get rid of the decimal with various code, but It will probably be inefficient as DataFrames get larger.

Current code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [np.NaN,np.NaN,3,4,5,5,3,1,5,np.NaN], 
                    'B' : [1,0,3,5,0,0,np.NaN,9,0,0], 
                    'C' : [10,0,30,50,0,0,4,10,1,0], 
                    'D' : [123456,123456,1234567,12345678,12345,12345,12345678,123456789,1234567,np.NaN],
                    'E' : ['Assign','Unassign','Assign','Ugly','Appreciate','Undo','Assign','Unicycle','Assign','Unicorn',]})

wow2 = df1
wow2['D'] = wow2['D'][:6]
print(wow2)

     A    B   C       D           E
0  NaN  1.0  10  123456      Assign
1  NaN  0.0   0  123456    Unassign
2  3.0  3.0  30  123456      Assign
3  4.0  5.0  50  123456        Ugly
4  5.0  0.0   0  12345.  Appreciate <--- Notice Decimal
5  5.0  0.0   0  12345.        Undo <--- Notice Decimal
6  3.0  NaN   4     NaN      Assign
7  1.0  9.0  10     NaN    Unicycle
8  5.0  0.0   1     NaN      Assign
9  NaN  0.0   0     NaN     Unicorn
```

**Is there a way I can leave the digit if it's length is not over 6?** I thought about converting the column to string and doing a loop... But I believe that would be wildly inefficient and create more problems than solutions

Comment: Do you need the first 6 values of a pandas Series or do you need the first 6 digits of all values in a pandas Series? At the moment, you select the first 6 values of your column D with `wow2['D'][:6]`. This does not change the actual values in your column but reduces your column D to only the first 6 values.

Comment: @pansen... you're right. Wow I completely missed that. Now my only thought is to change it to a string: `wow2['D'] = wow2['D'].apply(str).str[:6]` but then it still leaves the decimals and changes the NaNs to a string

Comment: Do you need to keep the np.NaN values or should they be replaced with some other value?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to keep them as np.NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first 6 digits of a number (without converting to string and back), you may use the modulo [operator](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mod.html). 
In order to represent your numeric values as non floating point numbers you need to convert them into integers. However, mixing integers and np.NaN within the same column will result into `float64` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value) for more). To get around this (which is kind of ugly) you need to convert the integers into strings which forces the dtype to be `object` because you mix strings and float values.

The solution looks like the following:

```
wow2['D'] = wow2['D'].mod(10**6)\
   .dropna()\
   .astype(int)\
   .astype(str)

print(wow['D'])

0    123456
1    123456
2    234567
3    345678
4     12345
5     12345
6    345678
7    456789
8    234567
9       NaN
Name: D, dtype: object
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! If possible, could you explain why `dropna()` is in there?

Comment: I also notice that I cannot run your part of the code without a fresh copy of df1 being created. even adding `.copy()` to the end of all of the `astype()` does not work. Any idea why?

Comment: @MattR First, dropna() is used to remove np.NaN values before converting to integers and strings. Otherwise you are going to have "nan" strings instead of np.NaN values. Second, your *fresh copy* comment indicates that you are trying to apply the same operation multiple times on an already altered object. You can't execute the modulo operation on column D twice because the second time you have strings instead of numbers.

Comment: The OP asked the first six digits instead of the last six digits