# Why is NaN considered as a float?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In `pandas` when we are trying to cast  a series which contains `NaN` values to integer with a snippet such as below

`df.A = df.A.apply(int)` , i often see an error message

```
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

I understand that `NaN` values can't be converted to integer. But i am curious about the `ValueError` thrown in this case. it says **float**   NaN can't be converted to integer.

Is there any specific reason why `NaN` values are treated as float objects? or is this the case of some issue with the error messages displayed?

Comment: Because IEEE 754 formats include NAN in their definitions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754 (i.e. NaNs *are* [special instances of] floats)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The short answer is [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) specifies `NaN` as a `float` value.

As for what you should do about converting a `pd.Series` to specific numeric data types, I prefer to use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html) where possible. The below examples demonstrate why.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

s = pd.Series([1, 2.5, 3, 4, 5.5])        # s.dtype = float64
s = s.astype(float)                       # s.dtype = float64
s = pd.to_numeric(s, downcast='float')    # s.dtype = float32

t = pd.Series([1, np.nan, 3, 4, 5])       # s.dtype = float64
t = t.astype(int)                         # ValueError
t = pd.to_numeric(t, downcast='integer')  # s.dtype = float64

u = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])         # s.dtype = int64
u = u.astype(int)                         # s.dtype = int32
u = pd.to_numeric(u, downcast='integer')  # s.dtype = int8
```

Comment: I wasn't familiar with `to_numeric`, nice.

Answer (score 8):

It's worth thinking about what it means to say any number "is" a `float`. In CPython, the `float` type is implemented using `double` in C, which means they use [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) double precision.

In that standard, there are particular bit sequences which correspond to every floating point number that can be represented in the system (note not all possible numbers between the upper and lower bounds can be represented).

Additionally, there are a couple of special bit sequences which don't correspond to "regular" numbers and therefore cannot be converted to an integer.

- Two infinities: +∞ and −∞.
- Two kinds of `NaN`: a quiet `NaN` (`qNaN`) and a signaling `NaN` (`sNaN`).

To build a `float` with such values, you can use this call:

```
nan = float('nan')
inf = float('inf')
```

And you can see the same error when passing these values to the `int` constructor:

```
>>> int(nan)
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

>>> int(inf)
OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```