# Why does the data type of "np.NaN" belong to numpy.float64?

Tags: pandas

I created a single columen dataframe filled with np.nan as follows:

`df=pd.DataFrame([np.nan]*5)`

```
    0
0 NaN
1 NaN
2 NaN
3 NaN
4 NaN
```

when I try to look for the data type of `df.iloc[0,0]`, i.e. NaN, the value returns `numpy.float64`

I know that the `pd.isnull` function could correctly returns true for these np.NaN. However, I don't understand why the data type is a float?

Comment: Numpy defines it that way. `type(pd.np.nan)` is `float`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is NaN considered as a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558973/why-is-nan-considered-as-a-float)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NaN in numeric arrays

```
>>> a = float('inf')
>>> b = float('-inf')
>>> c = float('nan')
>>> a
inf
>>> b
-inf
>>> c
nan
```

NaN values propagate through all operations without raising an exception. For example:

```
>>> c = float('nan')
>>> c + 23
nan
>>> c / 2
nan
>>> c * 2
nan
>>> math.sqrt(c)
nan
>>>
```

If it's float type it helps Python during calculation.

Answer (score 2):

NumPy (np) uses the `IEEE Standard` for `Binary Floating-Point` for Arithmetic calculations `(IEEE 754)`. Thats why when you do any type of manipulation with NumPy it will return `Float`

```
>>> type(np.nan*5)
<class 'float'>
```