# python dataframe.at assignment with datatype change

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Please look the code and output.

May I know why the data type in *_state column are float instead of int and how to cast those data type to int?

Thanks,

**Code**

```
print(df_test)
for idx, row in df_test.iterrows():
    print(type(row['value']))
    df_test.at[idx, row['name'] + '_state'] = row['value']
print(df_test)
```

**Output**

```
        Message   name  value
0  Door_Started   Door      1
1    Light_open  Light      1

type 'int'
type 'int'

        Message   name  value  Door_state  Light_state
0  Door_Started   Door      1         1.0          NaN
1    Light_open  Light      1         NaN          1.0
```

Comment: The *_state columns are added on demand so I would like to cast those column dtype as int

Comment: got it. Please check the edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only assigning an integer to a single column `row['name'] + '_state'`. This causes, for any given index, `NaN` values to appear in other column(s).

`NaN` is considered `float` ([see here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558973/why-is-nan-considered-as-a-float)), so a mixture of `int` and `NaN` values will always be upcasted to `float`<sup>1</sup>, for any given series. You can check this for yourself:

```
type(np.nan)  # float
```

This usually does not break subsequent manipulations / calculations, and it is efficient to keep your series `float`. Converting such a series to `int` is not possible and workarounds are inefficient. Therefore, I advise you do nothing.

---

<sup>1</sup> This accommodative behaviour is described in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#attributes-and-the-raw-ndarray-s):

> **Note**: When working with heterogeneous data, **the dtype of the resulting ndarray will be chosen to accommodate** all of the data
>   involved. For example, if strings are involved, the result will be of
>   object dtype. If there are only floats and integers, the resulting
>   array will be of float dtype.

Answer (score 0):

use this after the code:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.0f}'.format
print(df)
```

@Jpp is correct there. This will just change your visual so you can print 1 instead of 1.0

Also if using this solution make sure you read about pd.reset_option too https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html