# Why column of int and NaN has float type

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, series

I have this dataframe:

```
data = {'one': pd.Series([1,2,3], index=['a','c','d'], dtype='i4')
        'two': pd.Series([4,7,2,2], index=['a','b','c','d'])}

pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am getting following output

```
    one two
a   1.0 4

b   NaN 7

c   2.0 2

d   3.0 2
```

Answer (score 2):

In Pandas / NumPy, `NaN` is a `float`:

```
assert type(np.nan) == float
```

Pandas sets the dtype for a series to accommodate all values, as [explained in the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#attributes-and-the-raw-ndarray-s):

> **Note**: When working with heterogeneous data, **the dtype of the resulting ndarray will be chosen to accommodate** all of the data
>   involved. For example, if strings are involved, the result will be of
>   object dtype. If there are only floats and integers, the resulting
>   array will be of float dtype.

Since a `float` series can accommodate `NaN` and `int` values, while an `int` series cannot accommodate `NaN`, your series will have dtype `float`.

See also [Why is NaN considered as a float?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48558973/why-is-nan-considered-as-a-float)

Answer (score 2):

Because of presence of `NaN` which is of type `np.nan` is float type.

Either provide some other value at index `b` in columne `one`

or you can remove it later on by using

```
df.one = df.one.fillna(what_ever_value)
df.one = df.one.astype(int)
```

but make sure first remove the `NaN` value.

Answer (score 1):

Because the `NaN` is in the column,

`NaN` is a float so,

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> type(np.nan)
<class 'float'>
>>>
```

it's a float because this works:

```
>>> float('NaN')
nan
>>>
```

everything in the columns should be a float