# Pandas DataFrame, default data type for 1, 2, 3, and NaN values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
d = {'one' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
  'two' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print df ['one']
```

Output:

```
    a    1.0

    b    2.0

    c    3.0

    d    NaN

Name: one, dtype: float64
```

The value is set as float

```
d = {'one' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c']),
  'two' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print df ['one']
```

Output:

```
a    1

b    2

c    3

Name: one, dtype: int64
```

But now the value is set as `int64`.

The difference is the first one, there is a `NaN` in the value.

What is the rule behind the set up of the data types in the above examples?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) inherits many bad decisions from [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy).

Refer to:

[Pandas Gotchas - Integer NA](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na)

[Numpy or Pandas, keeping array type as integer while having a nan value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value)

If you look at `type(df.iloc[3,0])`, you can see `nan` is of type `numpy.float64`, which forces type coercion of the entire column to floats. Basically, Pandas is garbage for dealing with nullable integers, and you just have to deal with them as floating point numbers. You can also use the object type to hold integers, if performance isn't a concern.

Answer (score 6):

Type of `NaN` is `float`, so pandas will infer all `ints` numbers to be `floats` too.

This can be easily checked :

```
>>> type(np.nan) 
float
```

I would recommend [this](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/07/21/ieee-arithmetic-python/) interesting read