# Handling float nan columns that need to be formatted without decimal places

Tags: python, dataframe, nan

What is the best method to convert a dataframe column (object) containing nan and floats 900.0 to nan and 900?

Comment: Are you asking how to convert the column to integer or do you just want to print it as an integer. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value).

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:
Input:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(['1.0','5.0',np.nan,'9.0', '100.0', np.nan, '500.0'], columns=['a'])

       a
0    1.0
1    5.0
2    NaN
3    9.0
4  100.0
5    NaN
6  500.0
```

Let's try this:

```
pd.to_numeric(df.a).fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str).mask(df.a.isnull())
```

Output:

```
0      1
1      5
2    NaN
3      9
4    100
5    NaN
6    500
Name: a, dtype: object
```