# pandas using Int64 (capitalized) by default, rather than the default int64 (lowercase)

Tags: pandas

I have Pandas v0.24+, and I'm looking through: [Keeping array type as integer while having a NaN value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value)

I'm getting the usual value errors by trying to read in Integer columns with nan values.

> Pandas: ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 33

This is because integer types cannot handle NA values. The problem is I don't actually know the datatypes of my csv - I'd still like pandas to 'infer' what they are. Is there a way it can do this while using `Int64` by default instead of `int64`, so that it doesn't halt and complain about NA values in the process?

EDIT: This is what happens

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
```

Then

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/christopherturnbull/DATA_SCIENCE/PointTopic/access_test_v3.py", line 18, in <module>
    df = mdb.read_table(rdb_file,'v31a_v8_oct20_point_topic_availability_deliverable_201118')
  File "/Users/christopherturnbull/DATA_SCIENCE/virtualenvs/pointtopic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas_access/__init__.py", line 127, in read_table
    return pd.read_csv(proc.stdout, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/christopherturnbull/DATA_SCIENCE/virtualenvs/pointtopic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Users/christopherturnbull/DATA_SCIENCE/virtualenvs/pointtopic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 460, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/Users/christopherturnbull/DATA_SCIENCE/virtualenvs/pointtopic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1198, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/Users/christopherturnbull/DATA_SCIENCE/virtualenvs/pointtopic/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2157, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 862, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 941, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1073, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1104, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 1198, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
ValueError: Integer column has NA values in column 33
```

But `df = pd.read_csv(file, header = None)` seems to work, although now I don't have the dtypes

Comment: Can you add the input, and the code you are using? So my question is why when you are reading the csv is this error thrown? I believe pandas by default will interpret columns with nan as float... So my guess is that you are converting the columns afterwards, so do you which columns to convert?

Comment: *"so that it doesn't halt and complain about NA values in the process"* is unclear, you need to post a reproducible snippet of data. Is this happening with `pd.read_csv()`, or which command? Post your code and the error you're getting.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know, you need to specify the dtype when reading csv, also in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24.2/user_guide/integer_na.html) of nullable integers for pandas 0.24 (removed in the [stable version](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html)), you can find the following:

> Pandas can represent integer data with possibly missing values using
> arrays.IntegerArray. This is an extension types implemented within
> pandas. It is not the default dtype for integers, and will not be
> inferred; you must explicitly pass the dtype into array() or Series

As an alternative you could use [convert_dtypes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html#pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = """val,col\n
       hello,1\n
       world,nan"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))
res = df.convert_dtypes()
print(res.dtypes)
```

**Output**

```
val    string
col     Int64
dtype: object
```

The documentation of convert_dtypes, states:

> convert_integer: bool, default True Whether, if possible, conversion
> can be done to integer extension types.

Note that in the example above the *original* dtype was float:

```
print(df.dtypes)
```

**Output** (for df resulting of using *read_csv*)

```
val     object
col    float64
dtype: object
```

**UPDATE**

It seems that something it throwing off the inference engine, but as the problem is located in column 33, you could specify the dtype for it, try:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype={33: pd.Int64Dtype()})
```

The reason that using

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
```

works, is that makes the header part of the column values, so as they are strings the columns are interpreted as dtype object, as in:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = """val,col,bad\n
       hello,1,1.5\n
       world,,2.3"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), header=None)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
              0    1    2
0           val  col  bad
1         hello    1  1.5
2         world  NaN  2.3
```

As it can be seen the headers are the values for the first row.