# pandas.read_csv: keep column as integer while having NaN values

Tags: python, pandas

I just converted to Python from R, and now I'm trying to read in data from a csv file.
I was very annoyed with all my integer columns being treated as floats, and after some digging I see that this is the problem:
[NumPy or Pandas: Keeping array type as integer while having a NaN value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value)

I see that the accepted answer gives me a hint as to where to go, but problem is that I have data with hundreds of columns, as is typical when doing data science, I suppose. So I don't want to specify for every column what type to use when reading in data with `read_csv`. This is fixed automatically in `R`.

Is it really this hard to use pandas to read in data in a proper way in Python?

**Source**: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support

Comment: @sammywemmy: how do you suggest I go about sharing sample data? Do you want me to share a csv file?

Comment: @Rafaelars: As I'm saying in my question, I do not want to explicitly state the types of all columns. And no, all columns are not integers.

Comment: @sammywemmy I mean, it is well known that `R` is able to do this, and that Python is not, so why must I show this? Read this for context: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/development/extending.html#extending-extension-types

Comment: and/or see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support

Answer (score 1):

You can try using:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./file.csv', dtype='Int64')
```

Edit: So that doesn't work for strings. Instead, try something like this:

```
for col in df.columns[df.isna().any()].tolist():
    if df[col].dtype == 'float':
        df[col] = df[col].astype('Int64')
```

Loop through each column that has an NA value and check it has type of `float`, then convert them to `Int64`

Comment: that will not work when the data has string types

Comment: Thank you for the contribution! That will work, I'm just seeking something that will fix this automatically for me. I'm surprised Python can't handle this in a nice way.

Comment: Happy to help! I don't think it's a problem with Python per se but more so a quirk of the Pandas library. You could possibly create your own `read_csv` function incorporating the above code, possibly as a module so that you can easily import it in the future?

Comment: I tried this and get
`TypeError: cannot safely cast non-equivalent float64 to int64` although I used `Int64` as in the code above. My Pandas version is '0.24.2'
`