# How can I create a column containing only Nones but of a specific type in Pandas?

Tags: pandas

I'm creating a table for a unit-test. In one scenario I'd like to test what happens if all the values in one column are Null, but of the correct type. If I create a test-table like this:

```
df0 = pandas.DataFrame(
        columns=["a", "b", "key"],
        data=[{"a": 4, "b": 5, "key": 1}, {"a": 3, "b": 9, "key": 2}],
    )
```

... then the type of column **b** defaults to `object`, simply because there's no information for pandas to know what kind of column it's supposed to be.

Is there an syntax I can use to tell Pandas what the type of the column ought to be? According to the docs, something like this ought to work:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(
        columns=["a", "b", "key"],
        data=[{"a": 7, "b": None, "key": 3}, {"a": 7, "b": None, "key": 1}],
        dtype={"b":int}
    )
```

Unfortunately, that gives an error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

So what's the correct way to do this? Ideally I'd like to do it in a single statement, but it's OK to create the table and then set the type.

**Update 0:**

I tried this, thanks to @anky's suggestion:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(
        columns=["a", "b", "key"],
        data=[{"a": 7, "b": None, "key": 3}, {"a": 7, "b": None, "key": 1}]
    ).astype(dtype={"b":numpy.int64})
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

**Update 1**:

This syntax based on @Aditya K's suggestion isn't quite right either:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(
        columns=["a", "b", "key"],
        data=[{"a": 7, "b": None, "key": 3}, {"a": 7, "b": None, "key": 1}],
        dtype={"b":numpy.int64}
    )
```

Gives this error:

```
TypeError: object of type 'type' has no len()
```

**Solution**

Thanks to @Anky for this solution:

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(
        columns=["a", "b", "key"],
        data=[{"a": 7, "b": None, "key": 3}, {"a": 7, "b": None, "key": 1}],
    ).astype({"b":"Int64"})
```

This gives the desired column types:

[image]

Comment: the you can use `astype` with a dict, however you would need `'Int64'` instead of `int` since  `int` doesnot support NoneTypes, something like : `pd.DataFrame(columns=["a", "b", "key"],data=[{"a": 7, "b": None, "key": 3}, {"a": 7, "b": None, "key": 1}], ).astype({"b":'Int64'})`

Comment: How about setting dtype as float32 like this `pandas.DataFrame(columns=["a", "b", "key"], data=[{"a": 7, "b": None, "key": 3}, {"a": 7, "b": None, "key": 1}], dtype=np.float32 )`

Comment: @anky, Something seems a bit wrong, can you see my first update?

Comment: That is not what i suggested in my comment, You should either use `{"b":"Int64"}` or `pd.Int64Dtype()` , this is not same as `np.int64` check this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html

Comment: Also not what I suggested in the comment either. It was `np.float32` and not `{'b':np.float32}`

Comment: @AdityaK, but Ionly want to cast a single column. Surely I need to use the dict-style syntax?

Comment: @anky thank you, kindly add your solution as an answer and I will mark it as correct.

Comment: If this [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value) your question, we can close it, else you can answer the question as well :) I am glad if I helped you. Thanks