# TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NAType'

Tags: python, pandas, null, dtype

I have a column in my dataframe that contains nan values and int values. The original dType was float64, but I was trying to change it to int6, and change nan values to np.nan. now I get this error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NAType' when trying to run imputation on it. In the following table, column is similar to "age"

```
data = {'name':  ['Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry','Alex', 'Ben', 'Marry'],
        'job': ['teacher', 'doctor', 'engineer','teacher', 'doctor', 'engineer'],
        'age': [27, 32, 78,27, 32, 78],
        'weight': [160, 209, 130,164, 206, 132],
        'date': ['6-12-2022', '6-12-2022', '6-12-2022','6-13-2022', '6-13-2022', '6-13-2022']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data) df

    |name   |job        |age|weight |date
|---|-------|-----------|---|-------|--------
|0  |Alex   |teacher    |27 |160    |6-12-2022
|1  |Ben    |doctor     |32 |209    |6-12-2022
|2  |Marry  |engineer   |78 |130    |6-12-2022
|3  |Alex   |teacher    |27 |164    |6-13-2022
|4  |Ben    |doctor     |32 |206    |6-13-2022
|5  |Marry  |engineer   |78 |132    |6-13-2022
|6  |Alex   |teacher    |NaN|NaN    |6-14-2022
|7  |Ben    |doctor     |NaN|NaN    |6-14-2022
|8  |Marry  |engineer   |NaN|NaN    |6-14-2022
```

and this is what I tried:

```
df['age']=df['age'].astype( dtype={'age': pd.Int8Dtype()})
df.loc[df.age== '<NA>', 'age']=np.nan
```

Is there any way to change float64 to smaller datatype without causing this issue?
Please advise, thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```py
df['age'] = df['age'].astype(dtype='Int64')
```

with extension datatype `Int64` (with a capitalized `I`) rather than the default `dtype` which is `int64` (lower case `i`). The latter throws an `IntCastingNaNError` while the former works smoothly.

This functionality was added to [Pandas 0.24](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support) and mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value).