# Split dataframe columns value prefix and make headers in python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, split

I have a traffic data that looks like this. Here, each column have data in format `meters:seconds`. Like in row 1 column 2, `57:9` represents `57` meters and `9` seconds.

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0:0 | 57:9 | 166:34 | 178:37 | 203:44 | 328:63 | 344:65 | 436:77 | 737:108 | None |
| 0:0 | 166:34 | 178:37 | 203:43 | 328:61 | 436:74 | 596:51 | 737:106 | None | None |
| 0:0 | 57:6 | 166:30 | 178:33 | 203:40 | 328:62 | 344:64 | 436:74 | 596:91 | None |
| 0:0 | 203:43 | 328:61 | None | None | None | None | None | None | None |
| 0:0 | 57:7 | 166:20 | 178:43 | 203:10 | 328:61 | None | None | None | None |

I want to extract `meters` values from the dataframe and store them in a list in ascending order. Then create a new dataframe in which the the column header will be the `meters` value (present in the list). Then it will match the `meter` value in the parent dataframe and add the corresponding `second` value beneath. The missing `meters:second` pair should be replaced by `NaN` and the current pair at the position would move to next column within same row.

The desired outcome is:
`list = [0,57,166,178,203,328,344,436,596,737]`

##### dataframe:

| 0 | 57 | 166 | 178 | 203 | 328 | 344 | 436 | 596 | 737 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 9 | 34 | 37 | 44 | 63 | 65 | 77 | NaN | 108 |
| 0 | NaN | 34 | 37 | 43 | 61 | NaN | 74 | 51 | 106 |
| 0 | 6 | 30 | 33 | 40 | 62 | 64 | 74 | 91 | None |
| 0 | NaN | NaN | NaN | 43 | 61 | None | None | None | None |
| 0 | 7 | 20 | 43 | 10 | 61 | None | None | None | None |

I know I must use a loop to iterate over whole dataframe. I am new to python so I am unable to solve this. I tried using `str.split()` but it work only on 1 column. I have 98 columns and 290 rows. This is just one month data. I will be having 12 month data. So, need suggestions and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
tmp = df1.apply(
    lambda x: dict(
        map(int, val.split(":"))
        for val in x
        if isinstance(val, str) and ":" in val
    ),
    axis=1,
).to_list()
out = pd.DataFrame(tmp)
print(out[sorted(out.columns)])
```

Prints:

```
   0    57    166   178  203  328   344   436   596    737
0    0  9.0  34.0  37.0   44   63  65.0  77.0   NaN  108.0
1    0  NaN  34.0  37.0   43   61   NaN  74.0  51.0  106.0
2    0  6.0  30.0  33.0   40   62  64.0  74.0  91.0    NaN
3    0  NaN   NaN   NaN   43   61   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
4    0  7.0  20.0  43.0   10   61   NaN   NaN   NaN    NaN
```

Comment: My original dataframe name is `df1`. I am getting this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: @Omicron See my edit.

Comment: the `out` creates the dataframe. But column names are not sorted. The print statement does sort, but I want them as a sorted dataframe.

Comment: @Omicron Try `out = out[sorted(out.columns)]`. Then `print(out)`

Comment: Cool. Only problem is the `floating numbers`. I wanted `int`. When I tried `out = out.astype('int64')`, it gave me this error: `IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer'

Comment: @Omicron For that question I suggest to read these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value (in short, try `out = out[sorted(out.columns)].round().astype("Int64")`)

Comment: Thank you :) It did worked. However it changed `NaN` to `<NA>`. But that's not a big deal. Also, this code also worked. `out = out.astype('Int64')`.

Comment: Can you please briefly explain what the code do? I am trying to figure it out but not getting the idea.

Comment: @Omicron I'm going through the dataframe row by row. In every cell I check if the data inside it is string and it contains `:`. If yes, I split the string to two and create a dictionary from every row. The collect these dictionaries to list and create new dataframe. Then sort the columns afterwards.