# How to make pandas read "not applicable" as a null value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Basically a column in my data frame has lat and long in integers but some entries have "not applicable". Due to this, the column has dtype of object. I want pandas to read the "not applicable" as null so i can treat the column like an integer series.

I haven't been able to find anything online so far but I recall having read something about this online.

Comment: Please add an example of the input data, so we could reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you already have a dataframe, just `replace()` those values with `nan` (pandas doesn't use `NULL` per se) and then optionally change the dtype?  But integers don't support `nan` either, so maybe you want `float`? Or... https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/integer_na.html

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11548005/numpy-or-pandas-keeping-array-type-as-integer-while-having-a-nan-value

Comment: Example data would be helpful. Lat / long in integer degrees sounds odd because that would be extremely imprecise. Why do you need integers anyway?

Answer (score 1):

If you're dealing with data from a file, you can check the `na_values` argument in the load functions (example with [pd.read_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html))

```py
df = pd.read_csv('examplefile.csv', na_values= 'not applicable')
```

This will tell pandas to treat every single cell that has 'not applicable' in it as a nan.

If your dataframe is something you've generated inside the program, you can change the values where 'not applicable' appears with [pd.replace()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

This will change the value you tell it to another value you tell the function:

```py
df.replace('not applicable', np.nan, inplace=True)
```

The inplace argument makes it so the dataframe gets updated, instead of returning it. if you don't want to use it, you can do `df = df.replace('not applicable', np.nan)`

Here, I've used numpy's NaN as the replacement, but you can tell it to replace with any value you want.

For changing the data type, you can use [pd.astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html)

Comment: The op wants the dtype to be an integer and not an Object (or, implicitly, a float). This doesn't fix that.

Comment: you can do [pd.astype()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) if you need, as far as I've seen, it's not needed

Comment: Your answer will retain the dtype of Object, the op *expressly* states they want to change the dtype. And `int` can't contain `nan`.

Comment: Again, I've used it a bunch of times and it changes the dtype acordingly, also you can use the astype as I said...

Comment: @MatBailie "or, implicitly, a float" -- Where did you get that from? OP said "treat the column like an integer series", and floats are "like" ints. And there won't be any massive numbers that could cause loss of precision because the range of lat and lon are small.

Comment: `int` dtype ***can not*** contain a NaN

Comment: Why so obsessed with that? lat and long usually are given with a ton of decimals, meaning they would be floats.