# Why did pandas changed my numbers from -1 to -1.0?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I did some pandas read / write functions such that my whole numbers now become float for some reason

`Open,5,0,-1,-1`

`Open,5.0,0.0,-1.0,-1.0`

I am not sure which function had specifically changed my data type without my knowledge. Now my data cannot be parsed through elasticsearch.

Here is my code sample where the functions occur.

```
def format_location(location):
    if location and isinstance(location, str) and re.match(r'^\d+$', location):  # Check if the cell contains only digits
        if len(location) == 3:
            return f"9{location}2"  # Prepend '9' and append '2' to 3-digit numbers
        elif len(location) == 5:
            return location  # Return the original 5-digit value
    return location  # Return the original value for non-numeric or incorrect length values
    
def drop_extra_column(input_directory, output_directory):
    # Check all files in the input directory
    for file in input_directory.iterdir():
        if file.suffix == '.csv':
            try:
                # Open the input CSV file and create an output file in the output directory
                with open(file, 'r', newline='') as input_file, \
                     open(os.path.join(output_directory, f"{file.name}"), 'w', newline='') as output_file:

                    reader = csv.reader(input_file)
                    writer = csv.writer(output_file)

                    for row in reader:
                        # Check if the row has more than 18 columns
                        if len(row) > 18:
                            row.pop(18)  # Remove the 19th column (index 18)

                        writer.writerow(row)

                    # print(f"Processed data saved to '{file.name}'")

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing file '{file.name}': {e}. Skipping this file.")
                continue

def process_csv_files(intermediate_directory, output_directory):
    # Check all files in the input directory
   for file in intermediate_directory.iterdir():
        if file.suffix == '.csv':
            try:
                # Read CSV file using Pandas
                df = pd.read_csv(file)

                # Apply formatting to 'location' column only for numeric cells
                if 'location' in df.columns:
                    df['location'] = df['location'].apply(format_location)

                # Define the output file path
                output_path = output_directory / f"{file.name}"

                # Write back to the CSV file in the output directory using Pandas
                df.to_csv(output_path, index=False)
                print(f"Formatted data saved to '{output_path}'")

            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error processing file '{file.name}': {e}. Skipping this file.")
                continue
```

Comment: Probably this happened with the reading or writing functions of Pandas. You could try `df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype={'your_column': int})`.

Comment: Thank you. I just did that.

`Error processing file 'events2023-01-24.csv': Integer column has NA values in column 8. Skipping this file.`

Now I get this. Presume Column 8 counts from zero? That column I checked has some blank cells for certain rows. How to handle this?

Comment: Please make a [mre], meaning minimal but complete code and some example data. If you need specifics, see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](/q/20109391/4518341).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Keeping array type as integer while having a NaN value](/q/11548005/4518341)

Comment: You can try to remove the rows with missing values.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my issue by forcing those troublesome columns with

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, dtype={'column': 'Int64'})
```

Comment: Your answer is a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/11548005/4518341. To avoid redundancy and promote a consolidated discussion, it's beneficial to check if a similar question has been addressed on Stack Overflow before providing an answer. If a related question exists, directing the post owner to the original link ensures that all pertinent discussions are centralized in one location. This promotes better organization and accessibility for users seeking information on the same topic.